# Adding user pointer using url

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to make an app that it would download an image that is saved in parse using an URL. I have uploaded the image in the class. If the user taps a URL from inside the app, I want it to put there user object id into the pointer so that it would appear in the collection view. Can this be done using swift? I have no clue where to start

Comment: wat you tried till now.

Comment: I have no idea where to start from.. I read the documentation but have no clue

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

Images in Parse are in binary format, in a `PFFile`. Each `PFFile` cannot be retrieved* unless it's associated with a `PFObject`. So let's say you created the class `Photo` that has 2 customized fields: `imageData` and `URL`.

`imageData` is of type `PFFile` and contains a reference to your `PFFile`. The `URL` property is of type `String` and as per your requirements, contains a `URL` that uniquely determines your `PFFile` location.

Now, to grab that `PFFile` object that contains the `imageData`, your client will use a `PFQuery` that filters out the `Photo` you want by using a predicate or `whereKey("URL", equalTo: "someURLHere")`.

That `PFQuery` will then return you the `Photo` object you created, and you'll be able to reconstruct an `UIImage` from the data you can obtain from your `PFFile`.